# Django on Debian

Tags: django, apache, debian, wsgi

so I use Debian 6.0.9 (squeeze).
I have my project that I coded locally, that I uploaded on my server in /home/project/
now I already have mysql, apache2.2.16 and a lot of different PHP websites hosted.

Here's a typical sites-enabled/* I use :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project.com
    ServerAlias www.project.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/project.com/htdocs/
</VirtualHost>
```

I installed wsgi mod and tried following what it says here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

and nothing works. I don't get how it could work anyway since I don't precise the URL I want to use for my project. The Documentation is really not clear... Anyone have a clue what I am supposed to do?

Edit : I forgot to write how my file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName project.com
ServerAlias project.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/project.com/htdocs

 WSGIScriptAlias / /home/project/project/wsgi.py
   <Directory /home/project/project>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>

   Alias /robots.txt /var/www/project.com/htdocs/robots.txt
   Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/project.com/htdocs/favicon.ico
   Alias /images /var/www/project.com/htdocs/images
   Alias /static /var/www/project.com/htdocs/static

   ErrorLog /var/www/project.com/logs/error.log
   CustomLog /var/www/project.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What you are supposed to do is follow those instructions. What, exactly, is not perfectly clear? What are you confused about? What does your sites-enabled configuration look like now? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Follow the instructions. Check Apache logs (errors and access) when accessing the URL. What is the error message.

Comment: I followed the instruction there, it doesn't work (500 internal server error). I tried what I found here as well : https://library.linode.com/frameworks/django-apache-mod-wsgi/debian-6-squeeze doesn't work.

Comment: If you get "500 internal server error" you should see the details in the Apache error logs. It might be useful for you to stop Apache and run it from command line with verbose.

Answer (score 1):

In your VirtualHost  def:
Make sure you configure:

- DocumentRoot, WSGIScriptAlias - configured properly is a MUST
- ErrorLog, CustomLog - it helps in debugging
- WSGIDaemonProcess and WSGIProcessGroup - is a good security practice

For example:

```
WSGIPythonHome PATH_TO_YOUR_PYTHON
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project.com
    ServerAlias www.project.com, *.project.*

    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/vhost_test_error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/vhost_test_access.log" combined

    WSGIDaemonProcess project processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}  python-path=PATH_TO_YOUR_VIRTUAL_ENV
    WSGIProcessGroup project

    #DocumentRoot /var/www/project.com/htdocs/
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/project.com/PATH_TO_DJANGO_PROJECT"
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/project.com/PATH_TO_DJANGO_PROJECT/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm trying to make it work without the Daemon for now (it's already complicated enough like that :s) see my edits, my virtualhost def are like that. Also I read that you shouldn't tell DocumentRoot your path to the django project as it shows your code source.

Comment: Than add at least WSGIScriptAlias. 500 internal server error might also mean that mod_wsgi is not working properly. mod_wsgi needs to be exactly for specific version of your Apache / python / django.

Comment: If you see errors from you application (Django or Python errors) or application is working than you know that mod_wsgi is working.

Comment: The thing is I cannot access my application :s I have a URL, I have a server where I hosted my files, but I cannot check if it works... Its driving me nuts. I'm reading everything I can and nothing helps.